# How to compare two NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsinteger

How do we compare two NSInteger numbers ? I have two NSIntegers and comparing them the regular way wasnt working.

```
if (NSIntegerNumber1 >= NSIntegerNumber2) {
    //do something
}
```

Eventhough, the first value was 13 and the second value was 17, the if loop is executing

Any idea ?

Comment: That's how you do it. Double-check their values: set a breakpoint right before the `if` and make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: NSInteger is alis for int. so it should work.
Other wise specify the type of NSIntegerNumber1 variable..

Comment: Are you sure these are NSInteger numbers? My guess is these are NSNumbers and you are trying to compare the pointers.

Comment: Make sure when you debug you are using p instead of po, thats what fixed my issue

Comment: Why would p understand types when po does not? If po does not know the type why does it print a seemingly valid value? Whatever the reasons, this helped me find my underlying issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSInteger int1;
NSInteger int2;

int1 = 13;
int2 = 17;

if (int1 > int2)
{
    NSLog(@"works");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`NSInteger` is just a typedef for a builtin integral type (e.g. `int` or `long`).

It is safe to compare using `a == b`.

Other common operators behave predictably: `!=`, `<=`, `<`, `>=` et al.

Finally, `NSInteger`'s underlying type varies by platform/architecture. It is not safe to assume it will always be 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: This should be voted up, as it explains the reasoning

Answer (score 12):

Well, since you have Integer and Number in the name, you might have declared the two values as NSNumber instead of NSInteger.  If so, then you need to do the following:

```
 if ([NSIntegerNumber1 intValue] >= [NSIntegerNumber2 intValue]) {
      // do something
 }
```

Otherwise it should work as is!

Answer (score 2):

When comparing integers, using this, would work just fine:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;

if (a < b) {

NSLog(@"%d is smaller than %d" a, b);   

}
```